# Black sceen trying to put a .Xib after Splash

Tags: ios8

I'm programming a App for iOS 8. I've a problem because i don't want use storyboard, I want to put a .xib file at the first time. Muy problem is that always, after splash be a black screen.

The Class who I want to put after Splash is LoginViewController

At general options, the "Main interface" is white (empty) (if put the name of the class, i've NSException (NSUknownException)).

In the .xib file i'have the files owner connected, and at the right side of the screen i've the name of the class at "Custom Class" (LoginViewController).

My appDelegate.h is: (I try with " @property (strong, nonatomic) LoginViewController *viewController;" too)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;


@end
```

My appDelegate.m is: (i try a lot of variants)

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.viewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

The LoginViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController
{

    IBOutlet UILabel *labelPrueba;
    IBOutlet UIButton *botonPrueba;

    IBOutlet UIButton *boton2prueba;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label2Prueba;

    IBOutlet UILabel *dsfd;
    IBOutlet UIButton *dfdf;
}

@end
```

The LoginViewController.m:

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    label2Prueba.text = @"laaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    NSLog(@"Entra en viewDidLoad");

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Someone can help me please. I'm going crazyyyyy.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was put this windows like init frame:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // That was the solution  
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // That was the solution

    self.viewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Thanks